My problem has related to digit sum
Let $n,m$ be the positive numbers. Let $f(n,m)$ be the smallest $k$ such that for all $a$ be the arbitrary positive number, $S(a),S(a+1),\cdots,S(a+k-1)$ has at least $m$ terms divisible by $n$, where $S(x)$ be the sum of digits of $x$.
Can we find the formula of $f(n,m)$?
Case $m=1$, we can find the formula in $A331788$ (OEIS) or https://oeis.org/A331787/a331787.pdf.
Case $n=1$, I can prove that $f(1,m)=m$.
Case $n=2$, I can prove that $f(2,m)=2m+1$.
Case $n=3$, I can prove that $f(3,m)=3m$.
Case $n=5$, I can prove that $f(5,m)=5m+4$.
Case $n=9$, I can prove that $f(9,m)=9m$.
My conjecture: $f(n,m)=f(n,1)+(m-1)n$.
Anyone have ideas for my problem?

That formula does not hold for $n=4$, by the linked OEIS $f(4,1)=7$, so supposedly $f(4,m)=4m+3$. Then $f(4,3)=15$, but checking $15$ consecutive integers $988,989,\dots,1002$ yields only two whose digit sum is divisible by $4$.

Oh thanks bro! My new conjecture: $S(1),\cdots,S(n)$ has no more than $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m}\right\rfloor$ numbers are divisible by $m$.
